# Chi-square test across individuals and vegetation types in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have the percent coverage of n different vegetation types for 7 different individuals.  I want to test for differences in the proportion of each vegetation type across individuals.  i.e. is the vegetation composition different for each individual animal.

My data are here:

```
Data <- structure(list(IndID = structure(1:7, .Label = c("P06", "P07", 
"P08", "P09", "P10", "P12", "P13"), class = "factor"), Veg_V5 = c(0.045766316507, 
0.047303689688, 0.056893590139, 0.084802462906, 0.014449872446, 
0.09738444453, 0.064187261724), Veg_V9 = c(0.027242512682, 0.01079714987, 
0.012227657897, 0.026879196141, 0.021744009456, 0.029065982461, 
0.024820709696), Veg_V10 = c(0.002943062934, 0, 0, 0.001453619133, 
0.008588378756, 0.002336001225, 0.002511397265), Veg_V22 = c(0.003658113678, 
0.045570323716, 0.014352618087, 0.016906270086, 2.6184082e-05, 
0.006985026615, 0.020037857581), Veg_V30 = c(0.044989888016, 
0.157895085047, 0.098651407329, 0.049046292964, 0.016522155474, 
0.023712327193, 0.033410648111), Veg_V36 = c(0.301082396555, 
0.168989950447, 0.237744931683, 0.183522585412, 0.549495395342, 
0.162585685291, 0.113300807806), Veg_V38 = c(0.001445445925, 
0.02179277676, 0.008123926425, 0.003347045588, 0.000179547988, 
0.00297935894, 0.005683969181), Veg_V42 = c(0.063734651727, 0.127944902779, 
0.157800483468, 0.088456921086, 0.042171333667, 0.09721594608, 
0.20011730518), Veg_V46 = c(0.145959349519, 0.007588438052, 0.014483143897, 
0.171957277954, 0.06263606371, 0.186129514035, 0.120301794236
), Veg_V48 = c(0.110133159021, 0.020085874391, 0.064156046217, 
0.083554457713, 0.157755350904, 0.090943208364, 0.045370444427
), Veg_V50 = c(0.001423963713, 5.2927205e-05, 0.000297598847, 
0.000977251683, 0.001642115973, 0.003239765634, 0.000373243755
), Veg_V58 = c(0.016387858254, 0, 0.000125304778, 0.007978368047, 
0.020808863686, 0.014659365067, 0.009144471993), Veg_V62 = c(0.008344304605, 
0.018028329287, 0.016555893762, 0.039039847447, 0.001369053408, 
0.040562172098, 0.074840704897), Veg_V71 = c(0.002301665485, 
0.003784295175, 0.004443098578, 0.002252495537, 0.000834150027, 
0.001799869797, 0.000538537418), Veg_V79 = c(0.006720863217, 
0.003810758778, 0.003988868759, 0.008653984679, 0.000796744196, 
0.023176195765, 0.013575408569), Veg_V82 = c(0.035850741597, 
0.004082010705, 0.008061274036, 0.026926321733, 0.016492230809, 
0.030038678053, 0.021861419926), Veg_V86 = c(0.000564675266, 
0.004366494433, 0.003498091713, 0.000838080086, 0, 9.9567265e-05, 
0.00046922072), Veg_V114 = c(0.065990283903, 0.009679062659, 
0.014723311388, 0.065269827484, 0.015530900957, 0.05101673496, 
0.04312031779), Veg_V118 = c(0.003670389227, 0, 0, 0.000790739684, 
0.0007518572, 0.002083253552, 0.002596710123)), .Names = c("IndID", 
"Veg_V5", "Veg_V9", "Veg_V10", "Veg_V22", "Veg_V30", "Veg_V36", 
"Veg_V38", "Veg_V42", "Veg_V46", "Veg_V48", "Veg_V50", "Veg_V58", 
"Veg_V62", "Veg_V71", "Veg_V79", "Veg_V82", "Veg_V86", "Veg_V114", 
"Veg_V118"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

A look like this:

```
  IndID     Veg_V5     Veg_V9     Veg_V10      Veg_V22    Veg_V30   Veg_V36
1   P06 0.04576632 0.02724251 0.002943063 3.658114e-03 0.04498989 0.3010824
2   P07 0.04730369 0.01079715 0.000000000 4.557032e-02 0.15789509 0.1689900
3   P08 0.05689359 0.01222766 0.000000000 1.435262e-02 0.09865141 0.2377449
4   P09 0.08480246 0.02687920 0.001453619 1.690627e-02 0.04904629 0.1835226
5   P10 0.01444987 0.02174401 0.008588379 2.618408e-05 0.01652216 0.5494954
6   P12 0.09738444 0.02906598 0.002336001 6.985027e-03 0.02371233 0.1625857
      Veg_V38    Veg_V42     Veg_V46    Veg_V48      Veg_V50      Veg_V58
1 0.001445446 0.06373465 0.145959350 0.11013316 0.0014239637 0.0163878583
2 0.021792777 0.12794490 0.007588438 0.02008587 0.0000529272 0.0000000000
3 0.008123926 0.15780048 0.014483144 0.06415605 0.0002975988 0.0001253048
4 0.003347046 0.08845692 0.171957278 0.08355446 0.0009772517 0.0079783680
5 0.000179548 0.04217133 0.062636064 0.15775535 0.0016421160 0.0208088637
6 0.002979359 0.09721595 0.186129514 0.09094321 0.0032397656 0.0146593651
      Veg_V62     Veg_V71      Veg_V79     Veg_V82      Veg_V86    Veg_V114
1 0.008344305 0.002301665 0.0067208632 0.035850742 5.646753e-04 0.065990284
2 0.018028329 0.003784295 0.0038107588 0.004082011 4.366494e-03 0.009679063
3 0.016555894 0.004443099 0.0039888688 0.008061274 3.498092e-03 0.014723311
4 0.039039847 0.002252496 0.0086539847 0.026926322 8.380801e-04 0.065269827
5 0.001369053 0.000834150 0.0007967442 0.016492231 0.000000e+00 0.015530901
6 0.040562172 0.001799870 0.0231761958 0.030038678 9.956727e-05 0.051016735
      Veg_V118
1 0.0036703892
2 0.0000000000
3 0.0000000000
4 0.0007907397
5 0.0007518572
6 0.0020832536
```

Because I want to test for differences in veg type as a function of individual, I do not think the simple code below is correct.

```
chisq.test(Data[,c(2:20)])
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also, as this post has stats themes rather the solely tech, I was not sure if I should post here orthe Exchange.

**EDIT: Change Data Format**

using the `melt()` function I can restructure the data to this:

library(reshape)
test <- melt(Data,id.vars=c(1), measure.vars=c(2:20))
test <- test[,c(2,3)]

```
> head(test)
  variable      value
1   Veg_V5 0.04576632
2   Veg_V5 0.04730369
3   Veg_V5 0.05689359
4   Veg_V5 0.08480246
5   Veg_V5 0.01444987
6   Veg_V5 0.09738444
```

Now with IndID excluded, can I test for differences in the test$value for each level of the test$variable?  I am interested in variation within the factor level not across, so a chi-sq test seems more appropriate that ANOVA.

test$variable is a factor with 19 levels each of which has 7 observations.

Now, with multiple observations for each factor level, how can I test for differences 
with in each factor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `chisq.test()` considers `Data` to be a contingency table so you are not answering the question you are interested in.

From what I understand of your question, you are comparing one measurement from an individual to another measurement from another individual.  The problem is that for each individual you only have one measurement and therefore you have no way to estimate the variance of the estimated proportion.  I would recommend you consider what your hypothesis is and find the best test that fits it given your limited data.

Comment: I am trying to test if there are differences in the proportions within each column. I.e. within column 2 (Veg_V5) are the six proportions different?  However, as you say, this might not be possible given the limited data.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible without multiple observations per subject.

Comment: If you are still watching this post, I have changed my data structure and my question to address your comments.

Comment: You still have the problem of only one observation per subject.  If you have multiple measurements for each IndID for each level of variable, you could make inferences about within factor level differences.

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear.  I have changed my edits to exclude IndID.  I am no longer interested IndID.  I am simply trying to test for differences in test$value for each level of test$variable.  Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: To do that you need something to group the `values` by.  Since you are looking within each level of `variable`, you cannot use `variable`.  That leaves nothing else.  The best you can do is calculate descriptive statistics within levels of `variable`.

Comment: I was thinking I could calculate a mean for each factor level which would serve as the expected value and the compare the expected and observed (the test$value) values for each factor level.

Comment: I would imagine, though it has been a long time since mathematical statistics, you would want the expected and observed values to be independent, which they would not be if the expected is the mean of the values.